# Can someone walk through the preparation of a NEW Intel Mac installation of Ubuntu?

Tags: grub2, system-installation

I have tried to install ubuntu and I keep getting a fatal error when writing the grub-boot on to the drive.  I was wondering if I was missing a step, can someone please walk me through the process?

Again I'm using iMac mid-2020 intel based i7 with ubuntu 20.04.4 and attempting a triple boot with windows installed via boot loader.

Comment: "*a fatal error*" is unfortunately too vague to offer useful advice. Please edit your question to clearly describe what happens (since we cannot see it), including complete output and error message.

Comment: Did you try to disable secure boot and the T2 security chip?

Comment: I did the csrutil disable.  I went into recovery and allowed for any bootable source to be used.  I formatted the entire drive, yet when ubuntu went to write grub on the partition “fatal error occurred”. “The installation has failed.”  It tries to send a bug report but I have no internet so that fails as well.